# FormsAuthentication on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, appharbor

I upload my first ASP.NET MVC application to App Harbor, that uses FormsAuthentication to simple authentication of the user.

As usual on local machine operation that required authentications performes well, at the moment I tun them on AppHarbor, they failed.

I checked that authentication cookie released on access is send with the request, as it visible from image:

[image: screen shot]

and my server side authentication code looks like

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                        1,
                            user.UserName,
                            DateTime.Now,
                            DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                            true,
                            user.UserName
                        );

  string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
  this.Response.Cookies.Add(
        new HttpCookie(
              FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
              encTicket) 
  { Expires = authTicket.Expiration });
```

I read different posts from AppHarbor blogs like [ASP.NET Forms Authentication Considered Broken](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/22/asp-net-forms-authentication-considered-broken), it says "harmflul" and *not that it's not working*.

So, what I do wrong here ?

Comment: Are you using any Membership Providers?

Comment: no, no nothing.. Just form authentication cookie injection into the Responce.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/08/03/replacing-asp-net-forms-authentication

Comment: @Michael_B: yes :) I tried it, and it worked, apparently. Will add a post on this if no post will appear here. The thing is that in *that* case custom authentication used, but there is *no any post* (at least seems to me) that says that FormsAuthentication can not be used. I do not **currently** produce real-world application, but my concern is that custom authentication may not be better (from security point of view) as that one provided by MS itself. You will see that there is also Scott Hanselmann posts that strongly encourage them to consult some security agency on that subject.

Comment: I see. Well, hopefully, it will be addressed soon.

Comment: Forms authentication should work fine on AppHarbor. The standard membership provider (which uses forms auth) certainly works fine: http://www.nashcoding.com/2011/02/05/using-the-forms-authentication-membership-provider-on-appharbor/ - If you read the blog post, AppHarbor is not saying that the standard forms auth provider is broken in that it doesn't work, just that it's not very well built.

Comment: @friism: yes, correct. I say that according to AppHarbor post, it has to work, but it's not in my case, so I wondered why.